# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default_member_permissions' in {...}

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Recently, I updated my discordjs to v14 to use SlashCommandBuilder.

Once I finished to change all the files, I started my code and I saw this error :

`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default_member_permissions' in {"options":[],"name":"createcharacter","description":"Create your character","default_permission":false}`

The error is in the `node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js`

Here is the `ApplicationCommandManager.js` part of code :

```
let default_member_permissions;

    if ('default_member_permissions' in command) {
      default_member_permissions = command.default_member_permissions
        ? new PermissionsBitField(BigInt(command.default_member_permissions)).bitfield.toString()
        : command.default_member_permissions;
    }

    if ('defaultMemberPermissions' in command) {
      default_member_permissions =
        command.defaultMemberPermissions !== null
          ? new PermissionsBitField(command.defaultMemberPermissions).bitfield.toString()
          : command.defaultMemberPermissions;
    }
```

And here is my `createcharacter.js` command file :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const uri =
  "uri";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("createcharacter")
    .setDescription("Create your character")
    .setDefaultPermission(false),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const userId = interaction.user.id;

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's name?");
    const name = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's house?");
    const house = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's wand?");
    const wand = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's patronus?");
    const patronus = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    client.connect().then(
      // success
      () => {
        console.log("Connection successful");

        const collection = client.db("WizardryBot").collection("characters");
        let documentToInsert = {
          userId: userId,
          name: name.first().content,
          house: house.first().content,
          wand: wand.first().content,
          patronus: patronus.first().content,
          experience: 0,
          money: 0,
          quidditchxp: 0,
        };

        function userOwnCharacter(userId) {
          return collection
            .findOne({ userId: userId })
            .then((result) => Promise.resolve(result !== null))
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
        }

        userOwnCharacter(userId)
          .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log("User owns a character");
              return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
              console.log("User does not own any character");

              return collection.insertOne(documentToInsert).then(
                (insertedDocument) => {
                  console.log("Data inserted");
                  // console.log(JSON.stringify(insertedDocument, null, 2));

                  const characterEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Character Information")
                    .addField("Name", name.first().content)
                    .addField("House", house.first().content)
                    .addField("Wand", wand.first().content)
                    .addField("Patronus", patronus.first().content)
                    .setColor("#0099ff");

                  interaction.reply({ embeds: [characterEmbed] });

                  return Promise.resolve();
                },
                (reason) => {
                  console.log("Failed to insert document", reason);
                  return Promise.reject(reason);
                }
              );
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            console.log("Closing db connection");
            client.close();
          });
      },
      // failure
      (reason) => {
        // Connection failed with reason
        console.log("Connection failed", reason);
      }
    );
  },
};
```

I really don't understand this error.

If you could help I will be thankfull

I've tried to change :

```
let default_member_permissions;

    if ('default_member_permissions' in command) {
      default_member_permissions = command.default_member_permissions
        ? new PermissionsBitField(BigInt(command.default_member_permissions)).bitfield.toString()
        : command.default_member_permissions;
    }

    if ('defaultMemberPermissions' in command) {
      default_member_permissions =
        command.defaultMemberPermissions !== null
          ? new PermissionsBitField(command.defaultMemberPermissions).bitfield.toString()
          : command.defaultMemberPermissions;
    }
```

To :

```
let default_member_permissions;

    if ('default_member_permissions'.includes(command)) {
      default_member_permissions = command.default_member_permissions
        ? new PermissionsBitField(BigInt(command.default_member_permissions)).bitfield.toString()
        : command.default_member_permissions;
    }

    if ('defaultMemberPermissions'.includes(command)) {
      default_member_permissions =
        command.defaultMemberPermissions !== null
          ? new PermissionsBitField(command.defaultMemberPermissions).bitfield.toString()
          : command.defaultMemberPermissions;
    }
```

But it display this error :

`name: command.name,`

From this part of code in the `ApplicationCommandManager.js` :

```
return {
      name: command.name,
      name_localizations: command.nameLocalizations ?? command.name_localizations,
      description: command.description,
      description_localizations: command.descriptionLocalizations ?? command.description_localizations,
      type: command.type,
      options: command.options?.map(o => ApplicationCommand.transformOption(o)),
      default_member_permissions,
      dm_permission: command.dmPermission ?? command.dm_permission,
    };
```

Comment: This error usually means that `command` is not an object. You can try adding `console.log(command)` before it throws and try to find out what is it

Comment: I don't understand because, normally I don't have to change the content of a file in node_modules